# Why does my code output the shapes on top of each other and at the wrong spots?

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame

This part of my code is meant to create two shapes on either side of shape already displayed.

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, button_positions[i], button_radius)
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, white, button_star_points[i])
        if i == 0:
            g = random.choice([1,2])
            if g == 1:
                j = 2
            elif g == 2:
                j = 1
        if i == 1:
            g = random.choice([0,2])
            if g == 0:
                j = 2
            elif g == 2:
                j = 0
        if i == 2:
            g = random.choice([0,1])
            if g == 0:
                j = 1
            elif g == 1:
                j = 0

        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, white, button_triangle_points[g])
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, white, button_heart_points[j])
        pygame.display.update()
```

Here is the full code block for reference.

```
import pygame
import csv
import time 
import math
import random
from datetime import datetime
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
#from picamera2 import Picamera2 , Preview
#from libcamera import controls
#from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder

# Constants
ITI = 2 # Inter-trial interval in seconds

# Initialize pygame starts
pygame.init()

# Set the dimensions of the screen
screen_width = 1275
screen_height = 750

# Set the colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# Set the font
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 20)

# Set the button properties
button_radius = 70
button_x_spacing = 400
button_y_spacing = 200

# Set the button positions
button_positions = [
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing),
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 200),
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 400)
]

# Drawing Star Function
def generate_star_points(center_x, center_y, outer_radius, inner_radius, points):
    star_points = []
    step = 2 * math.pi / points
    half_step = step / 2
    start_angle = -math.pi * 2 # Start the star with one point facing to the right

    for i in range(points):
        set_point = lambda angle, radius: (
            int(center_x + math.cos(angle - start_angle) * radius),
            int(center_y - math.sin(angle - start_angle) * radius)
        )
        outer_point_angle = i * step
        inner_point_angle = outer_point_angle + half_step
        star_points.append(set_point(outer_point_angle, outer_radius))
        star_points.append(set_point(inner_point_angle, inner_radius))

    return star_points

# Create the star points for each button
num_points = 5  # Number of points in the star
outer_radius = button_radius  # Outer radius of the star
inner_radius = button_radius * 0.5  # Inner radius of the star

# List for star points
button_star_points1 = generate_star_points(button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing, outer_radius, inner_radius, num_points)
button_star_points2 = generate_star_points(button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 200, outer_radius, inner_radius, num_points)
button_star_points3 = generate_star_points(button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 400, outer_radius, inner_radius, num_points)
button_star_points = [button_star_points1, button_star_points2, button_star_points3]

# Creating the triangle points
def create_triangle(center_x, center_y, radius):
    num_points = 3  # For a triangle
    points = []
    for i in range(num_points):
        angle = 2 * math.pi * i / num_points
        x = center_x + int(radius * math.cos(angle))
        y = center_y + int(radius * math.sin(angle))
        points.append((x, y))
    return points

# List for triangle points
button_triangle_points1 = create_triangle(button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing, button_radius)
button_triangle_points2 = create_triangle(button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 200, button_radius)
button_triangle_points3 = create_triangle(button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 400, button_radius)
button_triangle_points = [button_triangle_points1, button_triangle_points2, button_triangle_points3]


button_heart_points1 = []
button_heart_points2 = []
button_heart_points3 = []
num_points = 100  # Increase this value for a smoother heart shape
radius = button_radius

for i in range(num_points):
    angle = 2 * math.pi * i / num_points
    x1 = button_x_spacing + int(radius * (13 * math.cos(angle) - 5 * math.cos(2 * angle) - 2 * math.cos(3 * angle) - math.cos(4 * angle)) / 16)
    y1 = button_y_spacing + int(radius * math.sin(angle) ** 3)
    x2 = button_x_spacing + int(radius * (13 * math.cos(angle) - 5 * math.cos(2 * angle) - 2 * math.cos(3 * angle) - math.cos(4 * angle)) / 16)
    y2 = button_y_spacing + 200 + int(radius * math.sin(angle) ** 3)
    x3 = button_x_spacing + int(radius * (13 * math.cos(angle) - 5 * math.cos(2 * angle) - 2 * math.cos(3 * angle) - math.cos(4 * angle)) / 16)
    y3 = button_y_spacing + 400 + int(radius * math.sin(angle) ** 3)
    button_heart_points1.append((x1, y1))
    button_heart_points2.append((x2, y2))
    button_heart_points3.append((x3, y3))

button_heart_points = [button_heart_points1, button_heart_points2, button_heart_points3]

# Inputs
trials = int(input("Number of trials: "))
AnimalName = input("Animal Name: ")
Trial_Duration = int(input("Trial Duration (s): "))

# Setting up Camera
#camera = Picamera2()
#vidconfig = camera.create_video_configuration()
#camera.configure(vidconfig)
#encoder = H264Encoder(bitrate=10000000)
#vidname = f"{AnimalName}_WCST_S3_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}_Video.h264"
#camera.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)
#camera.start_recording(encoder,vidname)
#camera.annotate_text = f"{AnimalName}_WCST_S3_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}"


# Initialize the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

# Set the caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Marmoset Buttons")

# Set the clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Set the counters
correctleft = 0
correctmiddle = 0
correctright = 0
incorrectleft = 0
incorrectmiddle = 0
incorrectright = 0
trialnum = 0
timeouts = 0

# Set the lists
timelistleft = []
timelistmiddle = []
timelistright = []
summarysequence = []

# GPIO Setup
#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# Psuedorandom sequence of numbers
sequence = [1,1,2,2,1,2,1,0,1,1, 1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2,1,1, 2,1,0,1,2,1,1,0,1,2, 2,1,0,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,
           1,1,0,1,1,1,2,0,2,1, 2,1,0,1,0,1,1,2,2,1, 1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,2,2, 1,1,2,1,1,2,1,0,1,1,
           1,1,1,0,1,1,2,0,2,1, 0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,0, 1,1,0,1,1,2,1,2,1,0, 2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,
           1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,2, 1,2,1,0,1,2,2,2,1,0, 1,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,0,
           1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,1, 0,1,2,2,1,1,1,0,1,1, 1,0,1,2,0,1,0,1,1,2, 0,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,0,
           1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0, 1,2,2,1,0,1,1,2,0,1, 1,0,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,0, 1,0,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,
           1,2,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,0, 1,1,0,1,2,1,1,2,1,0, 1,2,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0, 1,2,0,2,1,2,1,0,0,1,
           1,1,1,1,0,0,1,2,0,1, 0,1,2,0,1,2,1,2,1,0, 1,0,1,2,1,1,2,0,1,2, 0,0,1,0,2,1,2,1,2,1,
           1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,0, 1,2,1,1,0,2,1,2,1,1, 1,2,2,1,1,2,1,0,0,1, 2,1,2,1,0,2,1,2,0,0,
           1,0,1,1,2,2,1,0,1,0, 0,1,2,1,1,0,1,2,0,1, 1,0,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,0, 1,2,0,0,2,1,0,2,1,1,
           1,1,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,1, 2,1,0,1,1,0,1,2,1,0, 0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1, 2,1,0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,
           1,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1, 2,1,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,2, 1,0,1,2,1,2,0,1,2,2, 2,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,1,
           1,2,1,0,1,2,0,2,2,2, 1,2,2,1,1,0,1,1,0,0, 1,1,0,1,0,0,1,2,1,2, 1,0,2,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,
           1,2,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1, 1,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,1,1, 1,2,1,0,2,2,1,2,0,1, 1,1,2,2,1,0,1,2,1,0,
           1,2,0,1,1,0,1,1,2,1, 1,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,1,0, 1,2,0,0,0,1,2,2,0,1, 0,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,
           1,1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2,1, 1,2,1,0,1,1,2,1,0,2, 1,0,2,2,1,0,1,0,2,1, 1,0,2,1,2,1,1,0,0,1,
           1,2,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,1, 1,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,1,0, 1,2,1,2,2,1,0,1,0,0, 2,1,0,2,0,1,0,1,2,1,
           1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1, 1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2,1,0, 2,1,2,2,1,0,1,0,1,1, 2,1,2,0,1,2,1,2,0,0,
           1,1,2,0,2,1,2,1,1,0, 1,2,1,0,0,1,1,2,1,2, 1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,0,0, 1,2,1,0,0,2,1,0,2,1,
           1,0,1,1,2,1,2,0,1,2, 2,1,0,1,1,0,1,2,1,0, 0,1,0,1,2,1,1,2,1,0, 2,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,1]

# Truncating list
#trials = int(input("Number of trials: "))
n = len(sequence)
for i in range(0, n - trials):
    sequence.pop()

# Setting up CSV title
thedatetime = datetime.now()
thetime = thedatetime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
title = f"{AnimalName}_WCST_S5a_SimpleShape2_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}.csv"

# Write headers to csv file
data = open(title, 'w')
writer = csv.writer(data)
writer.writerow(["Trial#", "Event Code", "Time"])

time_start = time.time()

# For loop parsing through sequence 
for i in sequence:

    trialnum += 1
    summarysequence.append(i)

    # Writing summary csv 
    if trialnum%10 == 0:
        if trialnum == 10:
            title2 = f"{AnimalName}_WCST_S5a_SimpleShape2_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}_Summary.txt"
            summary = open(title2, "a+")
            summary.write(f"Trial Duration: {Trial_Duration}\n")
            summary.write(f"ITI: {ITI}\n")
        meanleft = sum(timelistleft) / len(timelistleft)
        meanmiddle = sum(timelistmiddle) / len(timelistmiddle)
        meanright = sum(timelistright) / len(timelistright)
        summary.write(f"Completed Trials (saved every 10th): {trialnum}\n")
        summary.write("Sequence: " + str(summarysequence) + "\n")
        summary.write(f"Correct: {correctleft},{correctmiddle},{correctright}\n")
        summary.write(f"Incorrect: {incorrectleft},{incorrectmiddle},{incorrectright}\n")
        summary.write(f"Total Reward: {correctleft+correctmiddle+correctright}\n")
        summary.write(f"Total No Reponses: {timeouts}\n")
        summary.write(f"Mean Reaction Times: {meanleft}, {meanmiddle}, {meanright}\n")
        summary.write("------------------------------------------------------------\n")

    # Delay between buttons
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.update()

    # ITI
    time_before = time.time()
    loop_counter = 0
    
    while time.time() - time_before < ITI:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, pygame.Rect(button_x_spacing - 10, button_y_spacing + 200 - button_radius + 10, 20, button_radius*2 - 20))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, pygame.Rect(button_x_spacing - button_radius + 10, button_y_spacing + 200 - 10, button_radius*2 - 20, 20))
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(100)
        pygame.event.pump()
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            if i == 0:
                writer.writerow([trialnum, 210, time.time() - time_start])
            elif i == 1:
                writer.writerow([trialnum, 211, time.time() - time_start])
            elif i == 2:
                writer.writerow([trialnum, 212, time.time() - time_start])
    
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.update()

    # While loop variable 
    correct = False

    # Starts Timer 
    #start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    start_time = time.time()
    
    # Writing the button in csv file
    timedisplay = time.time()
    writer.writerow([trialnum, i, timedisplay - time_start])

    # Loops while button isn't correct 
    while correct == False:

        # Time out for 15 seconds 
        seconds = (time.time() - start_time)
        if seconds >= Trial_Duration:
            timeouts +=1
            timenow = time.time()
            writer.writerow([trialnum, 250, timenow - time_start])
            break

        # Checks when screen is touched 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                # Distance between point touched and button 
                distance_button = pygame.math.Vector2(button_positions[i]) - pygame.math.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

                # Checks if distance is within button 
                if distance_button.length() < button_radius:

                    correct = True
                    timecorrect = time.time()
                    writer.writerow([trialnum, 150, timecorrect - time_start])

                    # Reward
                    #GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
                    #GPIO.output(12,GPIO.HIGH)
                    #time.sleep(0.1)
                    #GPIO.output(12,GPIO.LOW)
                    #GPIO.cleanup()

                    # Counts which buttons were pressed 
                    if i == 0:
                        timecorrect = time.time()
                        timedifference = timecorrect - timedisplay
                        timelistleft.append(timedifference)
                        correctleft += 1
                    elif i == 1:
                        timecorrect = time.time()
                        timedifference = timecorrect - timedisplay
                        timelistmiddle.append(timedifference)
                        correctmiddle += 1
                    elif i == 2:
                        timecorrect = time.time()
                        timedifference = timecorrect - timedisplay
                        timelistright.append(timedifference)
                        correctright += 1

                # Counts when touch was outside of button 
                elif distance_button.length() > button_radius:
                    correct = True
                    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if y <= (screen_height/3):
                        incorrectleft += 1
                        timenow = time.time()
                        writer.writerow([trialnum, 201, timenow - time_start])
                    elif y <= 2*(screen_height/3):
                        incorrectmiddle += 1
                        timenow = time.time()
                        writer.writerow([trialnum, 200, timenow - time_start])
                    elif y > 2*(screen_height/3):
                        incorrectright += 1
                        timenow = time.time()
                        writer.writerow([trialnum, 202, timenow - time_start])   

        # Draws the button 
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, button_positions[i], button_radius)
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, white, button_star_points[i])
        if i == 0:
            g = random.choice([1,2])
            if g == 1:
                j = 2
            elif g == 2:
                j = 1
        if i == 1:
            g = random.choice([0,2])
            if g == 0:
                j = 2
            elif g == 2:
                j = 0
        if i == 2:
            g = random.choice([0,1])
            if g == 0:
                j = 1
            elif g == 1:
                j = 0

        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, white, button_triangle_points[g])
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, white, button_heart_points[j])
        pygame.display.update()

# Closing objects 
data.close()
summary_contents = summary.read()
print(summary_contents)
summary.close()
#camera.stop_recording()
#camera.stop_preview()
```

It displays both the triangle and the heart shape at both sides of the star. I want the heart shape on one side and the triangle on the other. I tried to test it out with just simple terminal print instead of drawing the shapes and it seemed to work.

[This is what the output looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O4dw.png)

I'm not sure how this is as inside the while loop I'm only calling for the shape to generate once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must select the random objects before the `while correct` loop, but not in the loop. The loop is run in each frame, if you select new random objects in each frame, they will be drawn on top each other.

```py
    if i == 0:
        g = random.choice([1,2])
        if g == 1:
            j = 2
        elif g == 2:
            j = 1
    if i == 1:
        g = random.choice([0,2])
        if g == 0:
            j = 2
        elif g == 2:
            j = 0
    if i == 2:
        g = random.choice([0,1])
        if g == 0:
            j = 1
        elif g == 1:
            j = 0

    # Loops while button isn't correct 
    while correct == False:

        # [...]
```